# How to sink data into a single json file using flink v1.13+?

Tags: json, apache-flink, flink-sql

I want to sink my filtered data into a single json file,but got several parts in an output directory. Here is my code:

```
         String sinkSql =
                "create TEMPORARY table FileSink(" +
                        "name STRING," +
                        "timestamps BIGINT," +
                        "temp DOUBLE" +
                        ") WITH(" +
                        "'connector'='filesystem'," +
                        "'path'='E:\\output'," +
                        "'format' ='json')";
        tableEnvironment.executeSql(sinkSql);

        filter.executeInsert("FileSink");
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a simple way to do this.

But what you could do is

- run the job with a parallelism of 1
- convert the result table into a datastream
- convert that stream of rows into a stream of json strings (which might be more easily done by converting rows to POJOs to json)
- use `stream.writeAsText("/path/to/file")` to produce the output

Flink 1.15 will add more JSON support in the table API. Perhaps with that release it will become possible to do this using the PrintSink -- not sure.